# How to merge SQL queries "NOT IN" and "IN"?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have three collections `C1`, `C2` and `C3` and I want get all the elements in `C3` that are in `C1` but not in `C2`.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM C3 
WHERE MyId IN (C1) 
  AND NOT IN (C2)
```

but I get this error:

> Syntax error: Encountered "IN" at line 1, column 161

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Just read the syntax rules: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php, you need an expression before every `(not) in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `C3` is a table and `C1/C2` are lists, you need:

```
SELECT * FROM C3 WHERE MyId IN (C1) AND MyId NOT IN (C2)
                       \__________/     \______________/
```

Each sub-condition joined with `and` or `or` must be complete, even if it's the same column. For example,

```
select name from people
    where gender in ('m','f')
    and age not in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
```

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks that's exactly what I needed and it worked!